# Why doesn't highlighted text show what data type the highlighted text is?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using pyton with VSC and ran into a problem while watching a tutorial; when highlighting a number in brackets, the data type doesn't show up, while it does in the tutorial. IE: when higlighting 4.5 in
`print(4.5)`, it should say **4.5: float** in a popup, but that doesn't happen. Can anybody help me?

Comment: print(type(4.5)) shows the data type. if you find a more accurate answer then explain your problem.

Comment: it does not show the `4.5:float` tooltip on my install, which tutorial are you talking about, what do you mean with `highlighted text`

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail? Such as providing effect pictures or more other information.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code does not have automatic intellisense, you need to download a language specific extention to use it.
Steps to download:

1. open the extentions menu located on the left toolbar (ctrl-shift-x).
2. search for python.
3. click `install` on the top result.
4. (optional) restart VSC, I don't know if it is necessary, but better safe then sorry.

I hope this fixes your problem :) .

Edit: I just checked, and after installing the extention will say something along the lines of 'reload to enable extention', if it does not, it doesn't need it. Otherwise, just click the text that says that.